# SQL Server : insert into new column doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, alter

What am I missing? I'm trying to alter a table with a new column and insert into it. Ultimately, I want to insert a variable `@loopcounter`. But it doesn't seem to recognize the new column.

Here's the table

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles].[UserId],
    [dbo].[UserProfile].[UserName],
    [dbo].[UserProfile].[CustomerId],
    [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles].[RoleId],
    [dbo].[webpages_Roles].[RoleName]
INTO
    #ControlTable
FROM 
    [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[UserProfile] ON [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles].[UserId] = [dbo].[UserProfile].UserId
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[webpages_Roles] ON [webpages_UsersInRoles].[RoleId]=[dbo].[webpages_Roles].[RoleId]
WHERE
    CustomerId = 'DEMO'
```

And the alter/insert:

```
ALTER TABLE #ControlTable
   ADD Loopfield INT;

INSERT INTO #ControlTable (Loopfield)
VALUES (1)

SELECT * FROM #ControlTable;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Are you doing this in one session/transaction?  If not your temp table wont be recognized outside the current session/transaction.

Comment: Looping, in SQL Server, is often a poor design choice. What is your end goal here? (I have a feeling this might be an xy question.)

Comment: Ultimately I want to loop through each item in the table to use this table as I insert into the user in role table to add certain users that have the same dealerid to a new role.

Comment: Why do you need a loop to do that? A dataset approach would seem a far better idea.

Comment: @Brad It doesn't recognize the column in the insert. I am running this in the same transaction. When I try to run this code, I get "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'tempdb.dbo.#ControlTable_______________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000061'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: @Larnu A dataset approach might work. Can you point me in the direction or explain how that would work in the scenario?

Comment: Not without really seeing your end goal, no. You'll probably be better posting a new question with what you have, and asking how you can change it to a dataset approach. Feel free to mention me here and post the link once you have and I'll be happy to try and help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
alter table #ControlTable add LoopField int identity(1, 1);
```

Or just create the table with an identity column:

```
SELECT identity(1, 1) as loopfield,
       [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles].[UserId],
       [dbo].[UserProfile].[UserName],
       [dbo].[UserProfile].[CustomerId],
       [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles].[RoleId],
       [dbo].[webpages_Roles].[RoleName]
```

Or, if you are not going to insert new rows into the table, `row_number()` is sufficient:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by (select null)) as loopfield,
       [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles].[UserId],
       [dbo].[UserProfile].[UserName],
       [dbo].[UserProfile].[CustomerId],
       [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles].[RoleId],
       [dbo].[webpages_Roles].[RoleName]
```

Comment: Considering the OP wants to loop (this seems like a bad idea in SQL Server though) then `ROW_NUMBER` will likely be the better candidate. An `IDENTITY` will often not be sequential, which could cause odd behaviour for their looping process.

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me.

```
create table #temp (name varchar(10));
insert into #temp values ('bob'), ('mary');
ALTER TABLE #temp
   ADD Loopfield INT;
declare @Loopfield int = 1;
INSERT INTO #temp (Loopfield)
VALUES (@Loopfield);
select * from #temp;
drop table #temp;
```